# Enabling the cursor tracking effect in the Windows 7 taskbar

Tags: windows-7

On my home machines (Home Premium x64 + good graphics hardware; Professional x86 + poor graphics hardware), active taskbar icons apply a visual effect based on the position of the mouse cursor. Transparencies are not enabled on the machine with poor graphics hardware so presumably it's also supported in software.

On my work machine (Professional x64 + good graphics hardware), however, the effect doesn't show. All other effects (glass, window previews, etc) are enabled so it's not a performance problem.

Any ideas on how to enable it, or why it would be disabled?

(It may sound petty, but I'm more interested in how it ended up configured this way.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what Aero effect you are talking about, however, you can configure most of them in the following way:

Go to `System Properties` In Control Panel or press <kbd>Windows Flag</kbd>+<kbd>Pause / Break</kbd>,

Next click `Advanced system settings` and click the `Settings` button under the Performance section.

[image]

I have put an arrow next to what I think you may be talking about - but not entirely sure.

Comment: That fixed it. Strange, it was already checked, but switching it off/on got it working.

Comment: +1, Glad it helped! Gremlins?